# Limiting download_links for ActiveAdmin based on AdminUser model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to limit who can access the csv/json/... exports in ActiveAdmin based on the field 'limited'. I'd like to a) hide the links and b) return nothing at all if the path were to get hit anyway

I tried the following:

```
index downloads_links: !current_admin_user.limited? do
  # ...
end
```

as well as

```
csv do
  return if current_admin_user.limited?
  # ...
end
```

I also briefly tried using procs and lambda's but that's probably not the solution here either?

Neither appear to work and are giving me nomethoderrors on ActiveAdmin::DSLResource and ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder respectively

Any tips are welcome, thank you

Comment: a number of reasons... different discussion :-)

Comment: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2039

Answer (score 1):

i was able to achieve this with a simple monkey patch, but i was using cancan. cancan helper method 'can?' worked fine, but i wasn't testing the 'current_admin_user'. please, try it

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    class PaginatedCollection
      def build_download_format_links(formats = self.class.formats)
        params = request.query_parameters.except :format, :commit
        links = formats.map { |format| link_to format.to_s.upcase, params: params, format: format }
        unless current_admin_user.limited?
          div :class => "download_links" do
            text_node [I18n.t('active_admin.download'), links].flatten.join("&nbsp;").html_safe
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

upd:
i've tried with current_admin_user, and it worked.

also if you need to limit the formats, you can redefine formats method it this module, using your 'limited' method:

```
module ActiveAdmin
    module Views
        class PaginatedCollection
            def formats
                if current_admin_user.limited?
                    @formats ||= [:csv] # anything you need for limited users
                else
                    @formats ||= [:csv, :xml, :json]
                end

                @formats.clone
            end
        end
    end
end
```